# SQL Server - Duplicate Table Permissions: What does a "Null" grantor signify?

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, sql-grant

We recently set up table-level permissions on a SQL server database, but there is an issue:

There are two permissions lines for each permission on the table (for a single user). One of these lines has a null grantor (with nothing checked on the permissions), the other has "dbo" as the grantor with the permissions we just set up.

What could be causing the duplicate permissions with the null grantor? Any ideas?

Comment: "Lines"? How are you viewing the permissions? Without knowing more, I'd guess that there is a higher level permission (say a schema- or database-level permission) that implies the permission that you're looking at. You can take a look at all permissions in the database in the sys.database_permissions view.

Answer (score 1):

Two permission lines typically show up whenever a database principal *other than dbo* has granted the permission. This is tracked because if `WITH GRANT OPTION` to the permission revoked all the prinicipals to which it has granted the permission have it revoked.

I have not seen any instance of a NULL grantor. I suspect the NULL grantor is the result of a revoked `WITH GRANT OPION`. Try clearing any of these that are set, granting them from dbo if appropriate, and see if the NULL lines go away. If they do I would not worry about it further; if they don't then you may have a more severe corruption somewhere.

Comment: I think it may be related to that - some items in the database principals table have null owners (according to the Microsoft site, this shouldn't occur).